# Add random spread to directional vector

Tags: vector, spread

Let's say I have a unit vector a = Vector(0,1,0) and I want to add a random spread of something between x = Vector(-0.2,0,-0.2) and y = Vector(0.2,0,0.2), how would I go about doing that?

If I were to simply generate a random vector between x and y, I'd get a value somewhere in the bounds of a square:

[image: square]

What I'd like instead is a value within the circle made up by x and y:

[image: circle]

This seems like a simple problem but I can't figure out the solution right now. Any help would be appreciated.

(I didn't ask this on mathoverflow since this isn't really a 'research level mathematics question')

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I read your question correctly, you want a vector in a random direction that's within a particular length (the radius of your circle).

The formula for a circle is: *x<sup>2</sup> + y<sup>2</sup> = r<sup>2</sup>*

So, if you have a maximum radius, **r**, that constrains the vector length, perhaps proceed something like this:

1. Choose a random value for **x**, that lies between **-r** and **+r**
2. Calculate a limit for randomising **y**, based on your chosen **x**, so **y<sub>lim</sub> = sqrt(r<sup>2</sup> - x<sup>2</sup>)**
3. Finally, choose a random value of **y** between **-y<sub>lim</sub>** and **+y<sub>lim</sub>**

That way, you get a random direction in **x** and a random direction in **y**, but the vector length will remain within **0** to **r** and so will be constrained within a circle of that radius.

In your example, it seems that **r** should be **sqrt(0.2<sup>2</sup>)** which is approximately **0.28284**.

**UPDATE**

As 3D vector has length (or magnitude) **sqrt(x<sup>2</sup>+y<sup>2</sup>+z<sup>2</sup>)** you could extend the technique to 3D although I would probably favour a different approach (which would also work for 2D).

1. Choose a random direction by choosing *any* **x**, **y** and **z**
2. Calculate the magnitude **m = sqrt(x<sup>2</sup>+y<sup>2</sup>+z<sup>2</sup>)**
3. Normalise the direction vector (by dividing each element by its magnitude), so **x = x/m**, **y = y/m**, **z=z/m**
4. Now choose a random length, **L** between **0** and **r**
5. Scale the direction vector by the random length. So **x = x * L**, **y = y * L**, **z = z * L**

Comment: Thanks, that did the trick. If I want to do this for 3 axes, would it be enough to do **zLim** = **sqrt(r² -x² -y²)** and use that to generate a random value for the third axis? I'm not entirely sure if that would give all 3 axes an equal chance?

Comment: @Silverlan see updated answer, this may be a better approach overall.